# Combine two customer inputs in shopify to one customer tag

Tags: shopify

How can i get this code to combine the information from the drop down and the customer input into a single customer tag?

```
            <div class="relative">
  <label for="SocialMediatype">Select a social media</label>
  <select id="socialmediatype" name="customer[tags]">
    <option>Discord</option>
    <option>Reddit</option>
    <option>Instagram</option>           
  </select>
</div>
        
        
        <label for="SocialMediaUsername">Social Media Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="customer[note]" id="socialuser" {% if socialuser %}value="{{ socialuser }}"{% endif %} >
        
        {% assign social = socialmediatype.id %}
        {% assign socialuser = socialmediatype.id %}
        
<input type="hidden" name="customer[tags]" id="socialName" value="{{social,  socialuser}}" >
```

Comment: you need to use the javascript to combine the value on clientside and then send it to the server to save, liquid approach is not working here due to server-side limitations.

Comment: I'm sorry I am relatively new to this.
I can get each individual input to post as a tag but i am not sure how to get them both to do it.
I saw some other posts where they said to create variables but i am not sure how to properly assign the input values to the variables or how to call the variables to be associated with the customer tags.

my work around currently is to send one input to customer[tags] and the other to customer[note]

Comment: I think you need to look for an expert for it, so expertly does the job for you.